# ImageMagick, Linux Terminal

Tags: node.js, linux, terminal, imagemagick, mirroring

I need some help with Terminal's ImageMagick.
I need to do a mirror effect for half of input image with ONE command.

I can do this with 4 command(cut to 2 image, copy 2nd image to 1st, mirroring 1st image and then save 2 parts into one), but it's so hard for my server and sometimes lagging when lot of people try to use this function.

```
convert images/kek.png -crop 50%x100% images/out.jpg
cp images/out-0.jpg images/out-1.jpg
convert images/out-0.jpg -flop images/out-0.jpg
convert +append images/out-1.jpg images/out-0.jpg images/out.jpg
```

Comment: What are your 4 commands?

Comment: @MarkSetchell 
 — convert images/kek.png -crop 50%x100% images/out.jpg >
 — cp images/out-0.jpg images/out-1.jpg >
 — convert images/out-0.jpg -flop images/out-0.jpg >
 — convert +append images/out-1.jpg images/out-0.jpg images/out.jpg

Comment: Please don't put code in comments - it is really hard to read. Instead, click  `edit` http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39805164/edit under your question and paste the code in there. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell 
[input](http://i.piccy.info/i9/54048f55f4e8c9c122ea009ef6a1478b/1475319795/26114/1028497/stack_input.jpg) | 
[result](http://i.piccy.info/i9/2af138b45d63ed66b98f6190bff6229c/1475319758/30595/1028497/out.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I think you need something like this:

```
convert kek.png -crop 50x100%+0+0 \( +clone -flop \) +append result.png
```

[image]

Explanation... by specifying the `+0+0` on the crop, you only get one resulting sub image (the left side) rather than two - one of which you don't need. If you specify a percentage on either dimension, the other is assumed to be a percentage too, so you don't need two percent signs. Once you have the left half, you start some *"aside processing"* in which you clone and flop the image. Then, after the *"aside processing"* is complete, you append that to the right of the original unflopped image.

**Original Answer**

Something like this maybe?

```
convert homer.png -alpha on \
      \( +clone -flip -channel A -evaluate multiply 0.4 +channel \) -append \
      granite.jpg +swap \
      -gravity North -geometry +0+5 -composite  result.png
```

[image]

Or when your Homer has a solid background:

[image]

Kudos to Anthony Thyssen for his excellent work [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/advanced/#reflections).

Start images are below:

[image][image]

Tags: ImageMagick, mirror, reflection, reflect

Comment: I idk how to share image there (BB code/HTML?), but i can take u link to example - https://pp.vk.me/c627124/v627124463/12c3f/_qG3XBNANAM.jpg

Comment: @NickDeny I don't understand what you want to do? Is that the starting image or the resulting image? What are your 4 commands?

Comment: it's resulting image. I was wrote code on topic-message.

Comment: Wow! Thank You! I mark that ur answer is useful, but it's not displayed. ;)